# Codeigniter 3: add class "has-error" to the form group containing an invalid field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, class

I have a form with text-fields defined as such (in the view file):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_input('email', '', [
        'type'  => 'text',
        'id'    => 'email', 
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'value' => '',
        'placeholder' => 'Email address',
        ]); 
    ?>
    <?php echo form_error('email'); ?> 
</div>
```

In the controller I have enabled error messages:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
```

I would like to add the class "has-error" to the `<div class="form-group">` when errors are displayed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
```

or if you want to implement validation via jquery you can add this line

```
highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else if(element.parent('.blocks').length){
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }else{
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained the desired effect through JavaScript with these few lines:

```
$('.form-group').each(function(){
        var error_msg = $(this).find(".error");
        if (error_msg.length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('has-error');
        }
});
```